# How to reduce number of identical queries when retrieving records in model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, query-analyzer

I have started using [query-analyzer](https://github.com/bratke/query-analyzer) and it's warning me about identical queries.

For context, I am loading 25 "posts" on the page, and the current user can "star" a post:

> 0.018s **25 identical queries** `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE N AS one FROM 'stars' WHERE 'stars'.'post_id' = N AND 'stars'.'user_id' = N LIMIT N`

This is the method in the User model:

```
def has_starred_post?(post)
  return false if post.nil?

  Star.where(post_id: post.id, user_id: self.id).exists?
end
```

How can I satisfy this warning by reducing the number of queries?

---

Update:

Per Taryn East's tip, I updated the `User` model method to:

```
def has_starred_post?(post)
  return false if post.nil?

  self.stars.where(post_id: post.id).exists?
  # OR post.stars.where(:user_id => self.id).exists?
end
```

Although this allows me to associate/cache the stars belonging to the User, I still have to use `where` to check if any of those stars belong to the post. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this kind of duplicate query by using associations - which are automatically cached by Rails.

```
class Post
   has_many :stars


class User
   def has_starred_post?(post)
     return false if post.nil?

     post.stars.exists?
   end
```

Or re-organise so it makes sense to your actual object model...

Comment: Hi Taryn thanks for your response. I have updated my question with your feedback, but I still have one more question if you have time. Thanks!

Comment: @JodyHeavener once an answer has been recieved it's not considered sporting to change the question.

Comment: But the question is the same?

Comment: @JodyHeavener - The example you have above looks like it should work.